Opening direct chat from within Telegram Mini-app
I have been trying to create a feature in my telegram mini-app where a user can open a direct chat with another user by clicking on an icon. The methods i have tried dont open up any chat.
I have tried using an image embedded in an anchor link tag like so: 


this didnt work. How can it be done pls. Thanks

If you have the username this will be the solution WebApp.openTelegramLink(https://t.me/username)
